# Graphs one below the other and text on the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I would like to have graphs one below the other and the text on the right. It should look something like this:

[image]

I'm almost there now. The only problem is that the text doesn't start from the top. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},,
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.5cm,
    y=0.5cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=8.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(2/437)*x^5 + (5/437)*x^4 - (90/437)*x^3 - (280/437)*x^2 + (800/437)*x + 7};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{5px}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.5cm,
    y=0.5cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=8.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(2/437)*x^5 + (5/437)*x^4 - (90/437)*x^3 - (280/437)*x^2 + (800/437)*x + 7};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{5px}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.5cm,
    y=0.5cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=6.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(10/437)*x^4 + (20/437)*x^3 - (270/437)*x^2 - (560/437)*x + (800/437)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 


\end{minipage}\hfill
\noindent 
\begin{minipage}[ht!]{0.55\linewidth}
\small
\begin{enumerate}
\item Alle Hoch- und Tiefpunkte haben eine gemeinsame Eigenschaft:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Welche Steigung hat der Graph zu f dort? 
\item Pr\"ufe das am Graphen von $f'$.
\end{enumerate}

\item Begründe, ob die Steigungsangabe in 1. sicher auf eine Extremstelle führt (Hinweis: 
"Stelle" steht für x-Wert; Extremstelle also für den x-Wert eines Hoch- oder Tiefpunktes). 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Prüfe alle 3 Nullstellen des Graphen von $f'$
\item Wie ist am Graphen von $f'$ zu erkennen, ob tatsächlich eine Extremstelle im Graphen von $f$ vorliegt?
\end{enumerate}

\item Versuche die Ergebnisse aus 1. und 2. jeweils als Antwortsatz zu den folgenden Fragen zu formulieren. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Welche Bedingung muss mindestens erfüllt sein für eine Extremstelle von $f(x)$ (s. 1.)?
\item Wie kann man sicher unter den potentiellen Extremstellenkandidaten (aus 1 und 3 a) die tatsächlichen herausfinden (s. 2.)?
\item Wann liegt bei einem x-Wert sicher ein Hoch- und wann ein Tiefpunkt von f(x) vor?
\end{enumerate}

\item Mathematiker nennen Bedingungen, die auf jeden Fall erfüllt sein müssen, "notwendige Bedingung". Aus einer notwendigen Bedingung für eine Extremstelle muss jedoch nicht zwangsläufig eine Extremstelle folgern. Kann man jedoch sicher auf eine Extremstelle schlie\ss{}en, so redet man von "hinreichender Bedingung".
\begin{enumerate}
\item Formuliere die notwendige Bedingung für die Existenz einer Extremstelle.
\item Formuliere die hinreichende Bedingung für die Existenz einer Extremstelle.
\end{enumerate}

\item Den Verlauf des $f'$-Graphen in der Umgebung einer Extremstelle kann man zusätzlich auch mit dem $f''$-Graphen beschreiben. 
Formuliere den Satz in 4b neu unter Rückgriff auf $f ''(x_E)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How can I achieve that the text begins at the top?

Comment: I suggest you put all graphs in one minipage and the text in another one. That should do the trick.

Comment: @SebGlav It doesn't work. I get the same result. The Graphs are left, but the text appears under the last graph

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change the size of your graphic to see what going on, try this code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\null
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},,
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.3cm,
    y=0.3cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=8.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(2/437)*x^5 + (5/437)*x^4 - (90/437)*x^3 - (280/437)*x^2 + (800/437)*x + 7};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{5px}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.3cm,
    y=0.3cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=8.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(2/437)*x^5 + (5/437)*x^4 - (90/437)*x^3 - (280/437)*x^2 + (800/437)*x + 7};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{5px}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    minor tick num=1,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\small $x$},
    ylabel={\small $y$},
    x=0.3cm,
    y=0.3cm,
    ytick={-6,-4,...,8},
    xtick={-8,-6,...,7},
    ymin=-5.33,
    ymax=6.33,
    xmin=-6.33,
    xmax=7.33,
]
\addplot [color=red, domain=-8:8, samples=300, thick] {(10/437)*x^4 + (20/437)*x^3 - (270/437)*x^2 - (560/437)*x + (800/437)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 


\end{minipage}\hfill
\noindent 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\small
\begin{enumerate}
\item Alle Hoch- und Tiefpunkte haben eine gemeinsame Eigenschaft:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Welche Steigung hat der Graph zu f dort? 
\item Pr\"ufe das am Graphen von $f'$.
\end{enumerate}

\item Begründe, ob die Steigungsangabe in 1. sicher auf eine Extremstelle führt (Hinweis: 
"Stelle" steht für x-Wert; Extremstelle also für den x-Wert eines Hoch- oder Tiefpunktes). 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Prüfe alle 3 Nullstellen des Graphen von $f'$
\item Wie ist am Graphen von $f'$ zu erkennen, ob tatsächlich eine Extremstelle im Graphen von $f$ vorliegt?
\end{enumerate}

\item Versuche die Ergebnisse aus 1. und 2. jeweils als Antwortsatz zu den folgenden Fragen zu formulieren. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Welche Bedingung muss mindestens erfüllt sein für eine Extremstelle von $f(x)$ (s. 1.)?
\item Wie kann man sicher unter den potentiellen Extremstellenkandidaten (aus 1 und 3 a) die tatsächlichen herausfinden (s. 2.)?
\item Wann liegt bei einem x-Wert sicher ein Hoch- und wann ein Tiefpunkt von f(x) vor?
\end{enumerate}

\item Mathematiker nennen Bedingungen, die auf jeden Fall erfüllt sein müssen, "notwendige Bedingung". Aus einer notwendigen Bedingung für eine Extremstelle muss jedoch nicht zwangsläufig eine Extremstelle folgern. Kann man jedoch sicher auf eine Extremstelle schlie\ss{}en, so redet man von "hinreichender Bedingung".
\begin{enumerate}
\item Formuliere die notwendige Bedingung für die Existenz einer Extremstelle.
\item Formuliere die hinreichende Bedingung für die Existenz einer Extremstelle.
\end{enumerate}

\item Den Verlauf des $f'$-Graphen in der Umgebung einer Extremstelle kann man zusätzlich auch mit dem $f''$-Graphen beschreiben. 
Formuliere den Satz in 4b neu unter Rückgriff auf $f ''(x_E)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm almost done. I have only the proble with the text. See my answer below

Comment: I have edited my question.